# Не выводит срез в QTextBrowser

Tags: python, pyqt5

```
text = open('text.txt').readlines()[18]      <=========== Так выводится текст
    self.list.setPlainText(text)                 


text = open('text.txt').readlines()[18:]      <=========== Через срез ошибка
    self.list.setPlainText(text)          
                                           TypeError: setPlainText(self, str): 
                                          argument 1 has unexpected type 'list'
```

Comment: Добро пожаловать на Stackoverflow! Отредактируйте, пожалуйста, Ваш вопрос так, чтобы на него можно было дать корректный ответ. Пока что не понятно ровным счётом ничего.

Comment: Вы уверены, что у Вас в `text.txt` более 18ти строк?

Comment: да, одна строка выводится, если срез указываю то ошибка.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Метод `setPlainText` принимает текст в виде строки, а срез списка представляет собой другой список.

Для установки значения при помощи этого метода, надо преобразовать список в строку:

```
lines = open('text.txt').readlines()
text = ""

for line in lines[18:]:
    text += line + '\n'

self.list.setPlainText(text)
```

P.S. Для работы с файлами лучше использовать [менеджеры контекста](https://pythonworld.ru/osnovy/with-as-menedzhery-konteksta.html):

```
with open('text.txt') as file:
    lines = file.readlines()
    text = ""

    for line in lines[18:]:
        text += line + '\n'

    self.list.setPlainText(text)
```

Это гарантирует закрытие файла в любом случае.